# What is a highest oxide of element?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, oxidation-state

When I go through oxides of period 3 elements in periodic table I came across a term "highest oxides" and when I searched I didn't found any appreciative answer for my question.

**What are highest oxides and why they are called so?**

Comment: In particule accelerator the remove all electrons of atoms. So you can make $\ce{Au}^{79+}$ http://www.rhichome.bnl.gov/RHIC/Runs/ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highest oxide of an element is the oxide compound of the element which has highest possible value of oxidation state of the element to which the oxygen is bonded. Particularly, the highest oxide of period 3 is **chlorine heptoxide**, $\ce{Cl2O7}$ in which chlorine's oxidation state is +VII.

In general, the highest oxide of transition metal which has oxidation value of + VIII is **ruthenium tetroxide**, $\ce{RuO4}$ and **osmium tetroxide**, $\ce{OsO4}$.